# How do we take limits when it tends to a constant

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\cot x - \cos x}{(\pi-2x)^3}}$$

my tutor said we should take the limit $\frac{\pi}{2} - h$ as the limit tends to a constant
can anyone explain what it means and when do we take $\frac{\pi}{2}  - h$

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of equations.

Comment: You should ask your tutor

Comment: Because it is always easier to work around $0$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I suppose it's your tutor who can, and should, explain best what that means. BTW, be careful about words. What _tends to_ something in your problem is the $x$ variable, not a limit. A limit does not _tend to_ a constant, but rather it _is_ a constant (provided it exists, of course).

Comment: im sorry for picture , honestly its my first time using this site and thnxx for replies

Answer (score 1):

Your tutor is basically saying put $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-h$ so as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$, $h\to 0$

By doing this it can simplify the limit and make it easier to solve

for example here we get
$$\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{\tan h -\sin h}{h^3}}$$
which is much easier work with since you can use l'hospital's rule or use taylor's series at zero expansions to calculate the limit.

Comment: thank you , i get it now